# How to pass parameters to rest web service without using the (?) Symbol?

Tags: c#, url, rest, parameters

I have developed a rest web service by using the following link

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/simplerestservice11172009221218PM/simplerestservice.aspx

Now, I am passing parameters to this rest web service by using URL. I am passing parameters as follows

http://localhost:50362/PMTSRest/Service.svc/GetProjects?ProjectID=1

Now I want to know is there any way to remove the question mark in the URL & instead of it use any other symbol or how to pass parameters to the rest web service without using the (?) symbol ? Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue?

Comment: You could use any structure that your server side is capable of decoding. Directory style with slashes, another symbol, etc... What benefits are you hoping to obtain by avoiding the `?` symbol?

Comment: Can you please explain in detail with coding example how to use dictionary style with slashes, another symbol etc ?

Comment: If you want "dictionary-style" (which I interpret to be the standard key/value pairs) - why *wouldn't* you use the standard query-string approach? I think understanding "why" is key to this question.

Comment: What are you trying to do and why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking how to put the parameters in a path segment.  e.g.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISearch
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Search/{name}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    string  GetGreeting(string name);
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, but how to pass the same variable if it is int ? (In the above case name is string). I am trying for int variable but it is giving error Operation 'GetTasksForThisProject' in contract 'ISearch' has a path variable named 'ProjectID' which does not have type 'string'.  Variables for UriTemplate path segments must have type 'string'.

Comment: [OperationContract]
    //[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetTasksForThisProject?ProjectID={ProjectID}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
             //UriTemplate = "/GetTasksForThisProject?ProjectID={ProjectID}",
             UriTemplate = "/GetTasksForThisProject/{ProjectID}",
             ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
             RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<Task> GetTasksForThisProject(int ProjectID);

Comment: @Shailesh  Accept the parameter as a string and then do int.Parse()

Comment: Yes, I got your answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use HTTP POST instead HTTP GET to hide these parameters?